# What conditions can be broken?

Tags: diablo-iii

Certain abilities (e.g. the Wizard's [Mirror Image](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/mirror-image)) can break conditions. In testing this, I discovered you can break at least Freeze, Root, and Snare.

I assume there are conditions that I can't break, so what conditions is is possible to break?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can break snare, jailed, slows, frozen, root - with Smokescreen.

I haven't tested the abilities of other classes, but suspect that if Mirror Image works in the same way you should be able to break all of the above as well. Diamond Skin however does not break the above controls, but can be activated during one of those states to get the absorption effect.

Answer (score 2):

As a demon hunter I have smoke screen which allows me to break snares. The only thing that is unbreakable is stun. Every other effect goes away, slow, frozen, root, etc. Also any form of one of the bosses picking you up you can not beak such as when Diablo captures you in the bone prism then picks you up. After you are caught you can not break that.